# Is there a way to center text/images without multiple clicks on items?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-fireworks

I was wondering if there is a way to center images/text without needing to click multiple items? Usually i will need to click multiple items in order to be able to align things. I am in a situation where i just want text in the center and i have nothing else to align it with. Is there any way with grids or something?

Answer (score 2):

You can set the center of the image, set guides either vertical or horizontal. After that, you can drag your text layer and if your snap settings are turned on to snap to guides, your text block should snap at the center. Of course if your text is left or right aligned and it has empty space around it, the alignment will not be perfect. But, you can select your text and set the text to be center aligned and all will be good. Here are the steps, to find the center of the canvas area:

1. Make sure your rulers are visible if not press Ctrl-R to make them visible
2. Press Ctrl-A to select the entire image area
3. Press Ctrl-T to bring up the Free Transform tool. This will show a frame around the image with square handles at the centers of each edge
4. Click on the left ruler and drag inward into the image area. This will display a guide. Drag the guide until it snaps to the center of the top or the bottom edge If the guide is not visible make it visible by pressing Ctrl-; which is a toggle to turn the guides on and off
5. Now drag a guide from the top ruler and snap it to the centers of the left and right edges
6. Press Esc to dismiss the free transform tool which only served to mark the center of the image

To center a layer, text or other, target that layer. Click on the inside of the image and drag the layer until it snaps to the guides, horizontal or vertical or both. Keep in mind that when you snap the text layer to the horizontal guide, it will snap at the top, center, and bottom. Use the snap that suits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

With the Move tool selected, use Ctrl + A to select everything on the layer you want centered. This is will activate the alignment tools and allow you to center within your selection (which is the size of the canvas).

If you have bits of images hanging off the sides of your canvas this solution isn't ideal, but if you're just trying to center text and smaller elements this should work fine.